# Xamarin Android handling position change

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Android with C#. I have an adapter that inflate Recycler View holder. The view holder have few text fields and a radio button. When it is checked, it should move to the bottom of the row and save the change to local DB. Then I use NotifyDataSetChanged() in the adapter. The problem that I experience is that once the radio button is clicked, it appears that other rows are clicked too. Also, sometimes when I click on the radio button it does not change the status to checked/unchecked.

This is the Adapter

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    if (holder is SelectedShoppingListViewHolder selectedShoppingViewHolder)
    {
        selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListItemId.Text = shoppingListItems[position].Id.ToString();
        if (shoppingListItems[position].IsChecked)
        {
            selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Checked = true;
        }
        selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListItemNameField.Text = shoppingListItems[position].ShoppingListItemName;
        selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListItemQuantityField.Text = shoppingListItems[position].ShoppingListItemQuantity.ToString();
        selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListMeasurementDropDown.SetSelection(shoppingListItems[position].ShoppingListItemMeasurement);

        selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (shoppingListItems[position].IsChecked)
            {
                selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Checked = false;
                Database.UpdateShoppingListItemIsChecked(shoppingListItems[position].Id, false);
                shoppingListItems = Database.GetAllShoppingListItemsByShopListId(this.shoppingListId).OrderBy(sli => sli.IsChecked).ToList();
                NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Checked = true;
                Database.UpdateShoppingListItemIsChecked(shoppingListItems[position].Id, true);
                shoppingListItems = Database.GetAllShoppingListItemsByShopListId(this.shoppingListId).OrderBy(sli => sli.IsChecked).ToList();
                NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        selectedShoppingViewHolder.deleteRowButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Database.DeleteShoppingListItemById(int.Parse(selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListItemId.Text));
            shoppingListItems.RemoveAt(position);
            NotifyItemRemoved(position);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (shoppingListItems[position].IsChecked)
{
    selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Checked = true;
}
```

From the code you posted above, I find there are some logic problems on your code. For example, we should assign the value to `radioButton.Checked` whether the value of `shoppingListItems[position].IsChecked` is `true` or `false`.

This should be:

```
  selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Checked = shoppingListItems[position].IsChecked;
```

Besides, you can simply the click event for your RadioButton,just as follows:

```
     YourItem item=   shoppingListItems[position];

     selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.SetOnClickListener(new MyRadioButtonClickedListener(item));
     selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Checked = item.IsChecked;



   class MyRadioButtonClickedListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        YourItem item;

        public MyRadioButtonClickedListener(YourItem item)
        {
            this.item = item;
        }
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            item.IsChecked = !item.IsChecked;

            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
```

You can refer to the following code:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            if (holder is SelectedShoppingListViewHolder selectedShoppingViewHolder)
            {

                YourItem item =  shoppingListItems[position];

                selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListItemId.Text = item.Id.ToString();

                //if (shoppingListItems[position].IsChecked)
                //{
                //    selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Checked = true;
                //}
                selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListItemNameField.Text = item.ShoppingListItemName;
                selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListItemQuantityField.Text = item.ShoppingListItemQuantity.ToString();
                selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListMeasurementDropDown.SetSelection(item.ShoppingListItemMeasurement);
    
                selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.SetOnClickListener(new MyRadioButtonClickedListener(item));
                
               //assign item.IsChecked to selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton
                selectedShoppingViewHolder.radioButton.Checked = item.IsChecked;


                selectedShoppingViewHolder.deleteRowButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Database.DeleteShoppingListItemById(int.Parse(selectedShoppingViewHolder.shoppingListItemId.Text));
                    shoppingListItems.RemoveAt(position);
                    NotifyItemRemoved(position);
                };
            }
        }
```

**Note:**

1.You can change the `YourItem` to your item model.

2.I don't quite understand why you're reloading the data after you changing the status of `RadioButton`, which may affect the display of the data.

```
 shoppingListItems = Database.GetAllShoppingListItemsByShopListId(this.shoppingListId).OrderBy(sli => sli.IsChecked).ToList();
```

You can update your database as follows:

```
   class MyRadioButtonClickedListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        YourItem item;

        public MyRadioButtonClickedListener(YourItem item)
        {
            this.item = item;
        }
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            item.IsChecked = !item.IsChecked;

            //update database here  
            Database.UpdateShoppingListItemIsChecked(item.Id, item.IsChecked);

            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Kiril, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.